# JAXB: Why does a value return null if I just set that value, and returns a real value when I set other values?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have generadet a java class from a xsd schema with `JAXB`.
In the the Main class I have a method called `recursiveNodeList(NodeList list)` that just takes a node list and iterates through it recursivly to get all values out of it.

Everything works except one thing that I cannot simply understand.

In the code below I have these two lines:

```
item.setNote("Notetest1");
item.setTitle("Title1");
```

When I run the code I get this output:

```
title->#text->Title1
note->#text->Notetest1
```

If I just use one of the lines, like:

```
item.setNote("Notetest1");
// item.setTitle("Title1"); /*commented out*/
```

I get this output:

```
item->note->null
```

Why is the note null if I just set that value and not call `setTitle()` and why does it have a value when I call both `setNote` and `setTitle?`

The code in its whole:

```
public class JavaXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        Item item = new Item();

        JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(item.getClass().getPackage().getName());        
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxb.createMarshaller();
        item.setNote("Notetest1");
        item.setTitle("Title1");


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument();
        marshaller.marshal(item, doc);

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();
        recursiveNodeList(nodeList);

    }

    public static void recursiveNodeList(NodeList nodeList) {
        for(int i = 0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node fstNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {             
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

                if(fstElmnt.getChildNodes().getLength() > 1) {
                    NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getChildNodes();
                    recursiveNodeList(fstNmElmntLst);
                } else {
                    NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getChildNodes();
                    if(((Node)fstNmElmntLst.item(0)) != null)
                        System.out.println(fstNode.getNodeName()+"->"+((Node)fstNmElmntLst.item(0)).getNodeName() + "->"+((Node)fstNmElmntLst.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another question: 
If I instead of setting the title and note, set the category like this:

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setStringOne("string1");
category.setStringTwo("string2");
item.setCategory(category);
```

Then the output would be:

```
item->category->string1string2
```

Is there any way to get the "string1" and "string2" values into separate variables without using string manipulation techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your `recursiveNodeList` method.  In the single element case you were hitting the `System.out.println` line with an `Element` node, and in the two element case you were hitting the `System.out.println` line with a `Text` node.  The code below will work, but probably needs cleaned up.

```
public static void recursiveNodeList(NodeList nodeList) {
    for(int i = 0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node fstNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {             
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

            if(fstElmnt.getChildNodes().getLength() > 1) {
                NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getChildNodes();
                recursiveNodeList(fstNmElmntLst);
            } else {
                NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getChildNodes();
                Node node = fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                if(node != null)
                    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        System.out.println(fstNode.getNodeName()+"->"+node.getNodeName() + "->"+((Element)node).getTextContent());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(fstNode.getNodeName()+"->"+node.getNodeName() + "->"+node.getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is creating the document correctly.  The original and updated errors you are seeing are due to the way you are processing the DOM nodes in recursiveNodeList.  If you are interested in continuing with that approach I would recommend stepping through the code and paying attention to when the current node corresponds to a tag (i.e. `note`) and is of type Element, and when it corresponds to text (i.e. `Notetest1`) and is of type Text.  Below I have given a new code example that uses XPath to introspect the document which you may find easier to use.

```
package forum9698306;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;    
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class JavaXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Item item = new Item();

        JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(item.getClass().getPackage().getName());        
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxb.createMarshaller();
        item.setNote("Notetest1");
        item.setTitle("Title1");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setStringOne("string1");
        category.setStringTwo("string2");
        item.setCategory(category);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument();
        marshaller.marshal(item, doc);

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("item/note/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
        System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("item/title/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
        System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("item/category/stringOne/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
        System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("item/category/stringTwo/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Notetest1
Title1
string1
string2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have not been working with XML that much before, but when does a node become a Text node?

Comment: Please, also have a look at my other question. Look at my edit (marked it with bold text) in my post above.

Comment: @Rox - I have updated my answer based on your updated, and provided an alternative that you may find easier to use.